# Google Page Speed-Like Image Optimization

Tags: pagespeed, image-optimization

My website has about 20 thousand product images. Google Page Speed tells me they can be optimized, and it's correct - the difference is huge. Google is able to maintain identical quality and reduce the image size by 70-90%, and Page Speed even optimizes them for me and provides me with a link to the optimized image. This would be great if I only had a few images, but I can't manually update 20k images. I don't want to make any programmatic changes to handle optimization, I'd rather just run all of my images through a piece of software that can optimize them and replace the existing images. I would greatly appreciate it if someone who has been through this before can recommend a good program that can accomplish a job of this size while still maintaining quality. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of images?  (ie: png, jpeg, ??)

Comment: these particular images are jpeg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using a service from Yahoo, SmushIt: http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/. It can handle several hundred images at a time. I tried uploading 2,500 and it froze, but had no problem doing 400-500. The compression isn't quite as good as Google's, as Google Page Speed still says it can compress some of them an additional 3-8%, however, I've noticed that Google will sometimes reduce image quality, whereas SmushIt maintained exact quality 100% of the time.

Comment: Smush.it doesn't allow images of size more than 1MB

Comment: Also note that Smush.it changed in a way that you can't select multiple images at once anymore. You need to select single images for each upload form element now. Sorry, but __that sucks__.

Comment: Yahoo! has shut down Smush.It API

Comment: Well, that escalated slowly.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using a Mac I'd recommend http://imageoptim.com since you just drag and drop the files. It saves the files in its original location.
For Windows on Adobe AIR some people seem to like Shrink O'Matic - http://toki-woki.net/p/Shrink-O-Matic/

Comment: Shrink-O-Matic does not optimize images (sometimes the saved image is even bigger) and seems to destroy animated GIFs (eg. loaders, only the first frame is saved).

Comment: https://imageoptim.com works for me. Thanks Marcus.

Comment: I've tried using image optim and google still says it can be reduced by over 70%

Comment: @Oliwol, perhaps the images are not the right size, meaning the size they're displayed on the page?

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://page-speed.googlecode.com/files/pagespeed_optimize_image.exe) is the download link for Page Speed image optimizer. Cheers!

Comment: You can use this executable within a batch or automatically run it on all images in your IDE/build environment. It's also possible to add it to the Windows Explorer context-menu: http://www.integraxor.com/blog/using-pagespeedpngout-to-compress-jpgpng-with-mouse-clicks/.

Comment: Is there a linux equivalent of this?

Comment: This link is dead, is there another place to get this?

Answer (score 4):

Your best best is to use Google's own PageSpeed script. Just install it on your server and you are good to go!
On Apache: [mod_pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/download)
On nginX: [ngx_pagespeed](https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed)

Comment: And on IIS: http://www.iispeed.com/

Answer (score -1):

This is perfect for image optimization for google: http://outcontrol.net/gpsio-google-page-speed-image-optimizer-optimizar-imagenes-para-google/

kj

Answer (score -2):

Never used it.  Sounds like it's up your alley though: http://www.imageoptimizer.net/Pages/Home.aspx

Looks like it adds some "promo" text to the bottom of the images unless you pay for it though.  Someone else might have a better option.

---

Almost forgot about this one: http://www.gimp.org/